# Calculating first derivative of graph with unknown function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Say I have a curve on an x-y graph. And say it is too "anomalous" to categorize as one of the well known graphs (example is y=x, y=1/x etc). How would I be able to graph the first derivative of this unstable curve?

Should I be using the following equation to find out?

$f'(a)=\lim _{h\to 0}{\frac {f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}}$

Comment: If $f$ is given explicitly, basically yes. What is $f$? Notice that not every function is differentiable.

Comment: @user251257 If by explicitly you mean the equation with respect to x, then no. I was wondering if by knowing the values of y at each x (at x= 3, y = 5, x=4 y=2 etc) I  can draw the graph of the first derivative. It probably should be differentiable everywhere.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is only given for discrete $x$ values, you can't say much.

Comment: Say, $x_n\to x$ and $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $\frac{f(x_n) - f(x)}{x_n - x}$ converges to $f'(x)$. You can't conclude the converse, that is, if the limit of $\frac{f(x_n) - f(x)}{x_n - x}$ exists, it doesn't necessarily follows that $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: @user251257 Is it possible to use the answer written here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/848287/248360?

Comment: It is the exact reason why discrete values won't sufficient. You need consider the slope near $x$ for $f'(x)$. Not just for some discrete values.

Comment: I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the goal is to recognize some of the common features of a graph, such as the minimas and maximas as well as the inflection points.

So, think about the minimas and maximas.  You have a minima and a maxima when the derivative is zero, right?  So, find your minimas and maximas and plot a zero for the derivative at that x-location.

Now, look at the direction that the curves are pointing.  If the curves are sloped up, the derivative will be positive.  If the curves are sloped down, the derivative will be negative.

Now, look at the inflection points on your graph.  Those are where the *2nd* derivative is zero, so these will be the minimas and maximas of your first derivative.

Using that information, you can usually make a basic sketch of a derivative of an unknown function.

Comment: Thank you for answering. That's what I also saw online, of how to build a basic sketch. I was looking for one step further, with a little more accuracy perhaps.

Comment: For more accuracy you can use a ruler to measure the slope at each point, and then just transfer that to a new graph.